# Remove list element based on part of a string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a long list `json_response` containing Twitter data. Some of the 293 elements in the list do not contain any tweets indicated by `'result_count': 0` and I want to delete those elements from `json_response`

The following should remove all elements containing `'result_count': 0`. However, nothing happens when the code is executed

```
json_response = [element for element in json_response if element != "'result_count': 0"]
```

A sample of `json_response` where only the second out of four elements contain tweets.

```
print(json.dumps(json_response[0:4], indent=4, sort_keys=True))
[
    {
        "meta": {
            "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fo77fw18ex7m9tkxtn5jx8qokz8y2l",
            "result_count": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "author_id": "751651375407181824",
                "created_at": "2019-12-16T02:10:22.000Z",
                "id": "1206396117425852417",
                "text": "Tarkanian libel lawsuit against Jacky Rosen, 2016 opponent, blocked by Nevada Supreme Court"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "7568942",
                "created_at": "2019-12-15T04:41:00.000Z",
                "id": "1206071638166507520",
                "text": "Tarkanian libel lawsuit against Jacky Rosen, 2016 opponent, blocked by Nevada Supreme Court Dismissed thanks to NV's anti-SLAPP law"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "2404787642",
                "created_at": "2019-12-13T18:40:32.000Z",
                "id": "1205558134317568000",
                "text": "Tarkanian libel lawsuit against Jacky Rosen, 2016 opponent, blocked by Nevada Supreme Court"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "245630545",
                "created_at": "2019-12-13T18:06:29.000Z",
                "id": "1205549565513883648",
                "text": "Attacks lobbed in the heat of a campaign don't end with the campaign, Part 2: Supreme Court  puts an end to Danny Tarkanian's libel lawsuit against Jacky Rosen for ads from a 2016 congressional campaign, also via @RileySnyder:"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "56440142",
                "created_at": "2019-12-12T22:26:06.000Z",
                "id": "1205252514070839296",
                "text": ".@DannyTarkanian libel lawsuit against @SenJackyRosen, 2016 opponent, blocked by Nevada Supreme Court via @RileySnyder\u200b"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "794407888567476224",
                "created_at": "2019-12-12T22:08:08.000Z",
                "id": "1205247991029755905",
                "text": "Tarkanian libel lawsuit against Jacky Rosen, 2016 opponent, blocked by Supreme Court\nVia @RileySnyder\n"
            }
        ],
        "includes": {
            "users": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2016-07-09T05:37:07.000Z",
                    "description": "Towanda!  from Fried Green Tomatoes",
                    "id": "751651375407181824",
                    "name": "Karen Gruber",
                    "username": "mail4ufromme1"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2007-07-18T20:09:04.000Z",
                    "description": "Full-time software engineering manager, part-time educator, constant student, backpacker and disliker of the Oxford comma.",
                    "id": "7568942",
                    "name": "Justin Yost",
                    "username": "justinyost"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2014-03-22T17:05:36.000Z",
                    "description": "",
                    "id": "2404787642",
                    "name": "James Egan",
                    "username": "JamesEganLaw"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2011-02-01T03:39:40.000Z",
                    "description": "Assistant editor and reporter @TheNVIndy covering statehouse elections and more. Co-host of @nvindyespanol's Cafecito. Email me: michelle@thenvindy.com",
                    "id": "245630545",
                    "name": "Michelle Rindels",
                    "username": "MichelleRindels"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2009-07-13T17:49:46.000Z",
                    "description": "Curious about Congress and the beautiful game. Following the Nevada delegation for @TheNVIndy",
                    "id": "56440142",
                    "name": "Humberto Sanchez",
                    "username": "hsanchez128"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2016-11-04T05:16:14.000Z",
                    "description": "Nonprofit news outlet reporting on Nevada politics, policy and people since 2017 | Your State. Your News. Your Voice. | ideas@thenvindy.com",
                    "id": "794407888567476224",
                    "name": "Nevada Independent",
                    "username": "TheNVIndy"
                }
            ]
        },
        "meta": {
            "newest_id": "1206396117425852417",
            "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fn0po9zgvw98j7w7sec5wgoh0s0rr1",
            "oldest_id": "1205247991029755905",
            "result_count": 6
        }
    },
    {
        "meta": {
            "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fosns35qj7v5486697crmsdhl6kku5",
            "result_count": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "meta": {
            "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fo77h5ma6xw9tghoz8z8l6hgq0shod",
            "result_count": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Why do you think it's a string? You did run `json.loads()` on it, right?

Comment: I ran `print(json.dumps(json_response[0:4], indent=4, sort_keys=True))` to get the sample output above. It is now added to the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input is ultimately just a list of dictionaries with `<key, dictionary>` pairs, this should do it:

```py
json_response = [element for element in json_response
                 if element['meta']['result_count'] > 0]
```

Comment: It might be worth adding the output for completeness, for example, a really succinct way is `print([d['meta']['result_count'] for d in result])` -> `[6]`